# Occasional Error Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a `listbox` to navigate between records on a form but I occasionally get `Error Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit` `Run-time Error 3020`
on `Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark`.
I can't seems to figure out what the problem is and was wondering if someone can help me with how to fix it.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Private Sub listBox_AfterUpdate()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    If Not IsNull(ItemNo) And Not IsNull(itemName) Then
        Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
        rs.FindFirst "[ItemNo] = '" & Me![listBox] & "'"
        If Not rs.NoMatch Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If IsNull(ItemNo) Or IsNull(itemName) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure that the listbox is unbound.

Comment: @Andre today I was going through the entire module, then I noticed that I had `Dim rs As Dao.Recordset` at the top. Removing it from the top and code works well and hasn't errored yet. Could this be the cause? Since the list box is used to navigate between records, it is bound to one column i.e the `ItemNumber` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably started to edit the record in the Form. Save the pending edits before moving to another record.

```
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        Me.Dirty = False  'Saves any pending changes.
        Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark  'Navigate to another record.
    End If
```

Comment: @Oliver Jacot-Descombes `Me.Dirty` as you indicated is evaluating to `False` there `Me.Dirty = False` still fires the same error.

Comment: Do you have another code that calls `rs.AddNew` or `rs.Edit`?

Comment: Not at all. The above is the only code I currently have in the module. Unless this line on form current event  `Me!listBox = Me.ItemNo` may be the culprit?

Comment: I must admit that I don't know why this happens. Something else: `rs.Close` `Set rs = Nothing` should be in the `Then` case after the `If Not rs.NoMatch Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark` line. Then the `Else` with the `Exit Sub` and the last `If` with the other `Exit Sub` are superfluous.

Comment: @Oliveir Jacot-Descombes I had `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset` at the top of the module. Removing it seems to solve the problem and the error has not occurred since. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue. For me at least, I noticed it would happen under the following conditions:

1. The form was in edit mode (dirty),
2. I click the item in the `listbox` which is the same record as the current record,
3. if I then make any edit in any field, the error happens as soon as I move away from that field.

I was able to prevent the error either by saving the record before setting `Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark` (as suggested by Olivier Jacot-Descombes) or by comparing the values of Me.Bookmark and rs.Bookmark to make sure they were not the same.

```
If StrComp(rs.Bookmark, Me.Bookmark, 0) <> 0 Then
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If
```